# _CastError (type 'Future<ByteData?>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<ByteData>' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a function that allows you to save the user's signature as an image in the phone but I receive an error.
Here is the function for backup

```
void handleSavedButtonPressed() async {
    RenderSignaturePad boundary = widget.signatureKey.currentContext!
        .findRenderObject() as RenderSignaturePad;

    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();

    ByteData byteData = await (image.toByteData(
      format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png,
    ) as FutureOr<ByteData>);

    final time = DateTime.now().millisecond;

    final name = "Signature_$time.png";

    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
      byteData.buffer.asUint8List(),
      quality: 100,
      name: name,
    );

    print(result);

    toastInfo(result.toString());

    widget.signatureKey.currentState!.clear();
  }
```

It is this line that lifts the exception

```
ByteData byteData = await (image.toByteData(
  format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png,
) as FutureOr<ByteData>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?

```
ByteData byteData = await (image.toByteData(
format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png,
) as Future<ByteData?>);
```